# Hindi font from google font not working in tinymce editor integrated in cakephp with elfinder

Tags: php, css, tinymce, font-face, webfonts

```
 private function preset($name){ 
    // Full Feature
    if($name == 'full'){ 
        return array( 
            'selector' => 'textarea',
            'theme' => 'modern',
            'plugins' => 'advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,hr,anchor,pagebreak,
                        searchreplace,wordcount,visualblocks,visualchars,code,fullscreen,
                        insertdatetime,media,nonbreaking,save,table,contextmenu,directionality,
                        emoticons,template,paste,textcolor,youtube,colorpicker',
            'relative_urls' => false,
            'browser_spellcheck' => true,
            'toolbar1' => 'insertfile, undo, redo, |, styleselect, fontselect, |, fontsizeselect, |, bold, italic, |, alignleft, aligncenter, alignright, alignjustify, |, bullist, numlist, outdent, indent',
            'toolbar2' => 'link, image, media, youtube, emoticons, |, colorpicker, forecolor, backcolor, |, preview, print, code',
            'language' => 'hi_IN',
            'content_css' => ['http://englishcosmos.in/exam/hindifont.css'],
             'font_formats' => 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;Poppins= poppins,sans-serif;Indie Flower=indie flower, cursive;Hind= hind,sans-serif',
            'image_advtab' => true,
            'file_browser_callback' => 'elFinderBrowser'

        ); 
    }
```

Here code has option to set font dropdown, fontsize. Here all fonts from google working but Hindi font not working.
Is there any solution that I can use hindi font from google or directly.
Font I want to use here is : Kurti Dev

Comment: Did you add the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in you html page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to expand it. Look at the option `content_css` of TinyMCE ([link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css)). Yes, U use it ( http://englishcosmos.in/exam/hindifont.css => `404` ). In that file U have to input something like :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Kruti Dev";
   src: url("../path_to_ttf-file/kruti.ttf");
}

body{
 font-family:'Kruti Dev', Verdana;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you to reply. I have done that. It is not working. Iplease suggest something anotger. I have googled all methids but not working

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Ok. What `font-famiy` of TinyMCE body do U see in console? Check it up.